# Do you need to install both cordova and phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am trying to get started with phonegap/cordova for developing mobile apps.

Still a lil confused by the getting started part of the website
http://docs.phonegap.com/

In one place,[CLI installation instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface), they say to install cordova.

IN another place,[Phonegap installation instructions](http://phonegap.com/install/), they say to install phonegap.

What's going on here? Do we need both? What is the difference in roles of each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is the engine that powers Chrome or Safari. (Browser geeks, please allow me the affordance of this analogy and I’ll buy you a beer later.)

Over time, the PhoneGap distribution may contain additional tools that tie into other Adobe services, which would not be appropriate for an Apache project. For example, PhoneGap Build and Adobe Shadow together make a whole lot of strategic sense. PhoneGap will always remain free, open source software and will always be a free distribution of Apache Cordova.

Currently, the only difference is in the name of the download package and will remain so for some time.

[more](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)

Comment: So if I understand you right. I could develop apps by just installing cordova. Am I right?

Comment: Yes @JayJayJay, you don't need to use PhoneGap at all to build apps. However, if you don't have a Mac and want to publish iOS apps, you could use PhoneGapBuild (it will offload your project to Adobe's build servers, some of which must be mac machines.)

Answer (score 1):

**The PhoneGap CLI is built on top of the Cordova CLI**. It has all of the functionality that the Cordova CLI has. The main difference is that the **PhoneGap CLI has PhoneGap Build integration**. So if you don’t have the native SDK installed, you can delegate compilation to the PhoneGap Build cloud service and get app-store ready mobile apps. Both tools are completely interoperable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. PhoneGap should include all of the commands that Cordova provides. It provides a cloud-based build feature, which Cordova does not.

The documentation on phonegap.com would benefit from clarifying its use of 'cordova' vs. 'phonegap'.  Right now, it is too easy for new developers to get confused over which commands are relevant.